# validate date as a required field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to validate a form using JS so that without filling some required fields, the form cannot be submitted.

For instance to set surname as required I used,

```
<script>

    function validateform(){
        var x=document.forms["vacancy"]["surname"].value;
        if(x==""){alert("Surname must be filled out");
                 return false;}
</script>
```

The form:

```
<form name="vacancy" action="" onSubmit="return validateform()">
Surname <input name="surname" type="text">
</form>
```

This code is perfectly fine but when I used the same for the field of birthday it proceeds without checking whether the field is provided.

```
<script> 
function validateform(){
var a=document.forms["vacancy"]["dob"].value;
        if(a==""){alert("Birthdate must be filled out");
                 return false;}
</script>

<form name="vacancy" action="" onSubmit="return validateform()">
 Date of Birth <input name="dob" type="date">
</form>
```

Is there any other way to check when the type is set to date?

Comment: Have you checked the value (`a`) that the field has if it isn't filled out?

Comment: yes. It still gives the default value mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Then there is your answer. `mm/dd/yyyy` is not the same as an empty string, which is what you are checking against (`a==""`)

Comment: How can the browser then know that the user has given an input or not? I need to make a message box pop up if an input is not given

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a typo in your second script: `finction validateform()`, where "finction" should be "function".

As an alternative you could just use the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) attribute for this.

```html
<form name="vacancy" action="">
  Surname <input name="surname" type="text" required></br>
  DOB <input name="dob" type="date" required></br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT (for edited question)**: Which browser are you using as your corrected code example works in the example below. If you are using both forms in the same page then the function declarations, `validateform`, would result in a name collision.

```html
<script>
  function validateform() {
    var a = document.forms["vacancy"]["dob"].value;
    if (a == "") {
      alert("Birthdate must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>

<form name="vacancy" action="" onSubmit="return validateform()">
  Date of Birth <input name="dob" type="date">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks i have corrected it. But it's still the same. Ideally the message box should pop up if DOB is not filled but when submitted it doesn't happen so.

Comment: @she_grab I've verified on Chrome, FF and Safari for OSX and it works... if the problem persists on your environment you could test for either an empty string OR whatever the default string value is showing for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if default value of 'mm/dd/yyyy' is still present in 'a' instead of empty string and then throw the message.

Comment: The default [*value format for a date input*](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#dates-and-times) is YYYY-MM-DD.